# How to make directive respond only to specific events broadcasted by an interceptor?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Currently I have an app that allows users to create "items", delete them, move them to different folders, etc.

I'll loosely defined these for now as "CRUD" operations. Any time a CRUD operation takes place on the client-side, the data of the item is also updated on the server.

I have an `$http` interceptor in my app's `.config` that, on success or error, will broadcast an event `_END_REQUEST_`, which is defined in my app as a `.constant` (whenever any request starts, a `_START_REQUEST_` event is also broadcasted).

I have a trash icon that, when pressed, deletes items that are checked. When the items are deleted, I'd like to show some sort of success message to the user (but **only** when an item is deleted, not when it is moved to a different folder, or whatever else.)

Currently, I have a directive of a loading icon that on `_START_REQUEST_` is set to `display: block`, and on `_END_REQUEST_` is set to `display: none`. This works for every request. I want my success message for when an item is deleted to only happen when an item is deleted, though.

I am using Node.js, so one option is to send back a json response with the type of request that was completed. For example:

```
// server
user.save(function(err) {
    if(err) res.send(500);

    res.json({'type': 'itemDeleted'});
});
```

```
// client
interceptor = ['$q', '$injector', function ($q, $injector) {
    var rootScope;

    function success(response) {
        // get $http via $injector because of circular dependency problem
        $http = $http || $injector.get('$http');
        // don't send notification until all requests are complete
        if ($http.pendingRequests.length < 1) {
            // get $rootScope via $injector because of circular dependency problem
            rootScope = rootScope || $injector.get('$rootScope');

            // send a notification requests are complete
            //check if it's an item (it will have a text field in data)
            if(response.data.type === 'itemDeleted') {
                rootScope.$broadcast(_ITEM_DELETED_);   
            }

            rootScope.$broadcast(_END_REQUEST_);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

This solution seems a bit less than elegant, though. If I scale this (say, I send back a type of 'itemSaved' or 'itemMoved'), I could potentially be broadcasting lots and lots of events that I have to keep track of. Is there a way to only have to broadcast one event (`_END_REQUEST_`) and still do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of differentiating between responses using additional events, pass an identifying flag along with any that are broadcasted which need to be identified by a listener.

Inside of your interceptor, it might look something like this:

```
'response': function(response) {
    var flag;
    if (response.data.type === 'itemDeleted') flag = 'deleted';
    $rootScope.$broadcast('_END_REQUEST_', flag);
    return response;
},
```

You could then check for this specific flag in any `$on` listener. For example:

```
directive('deleted', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {   
      scope.$on('_END_REQUEST_', function(event, flag) {
        if (flag === 'deleted') {
          scope.showDeleted = true;
          $timeout(function(){ scope.showDeleted = false }, 2000)
        } 
      })
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="showDeleted">Deleted</div>'
  }
})
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Skz96tENW9i4QCvFaT4r?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One change I made is using $rootScope.$emit and $rootScope.$on, just for performance.